# Slave index corruption mariadb 10.5

Tags: replication, index, mariadb, corruption

We have a simple mariadb replication with a master and a bunch of slaves. without any prior alert or warning, randomly in our slaves some indexes ( some of them are not present in master) become corrupted. This happened for us after migrating from we receive a bunch of error log each time. I mention them below:

```
2022-01-01 20:00:38 6 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Page old data size 13873 new data size 15584, page old max ins size 1920 new max ins size 209
220101 20:00:38 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
    This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
```

any recommendation would be appreciated.
if it helps we have a 56 core bare metal server with 180 Gig Ram and ssd. and our configuration and error log is available here:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27411

Comment: Include the full information, versions, configuration, the full log and a precise story in a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/).

Comment: If the problem is in an `INDEX`, consider DROPping and reCREATEing the index.